# LINQ left join using Castle Active Records?

Tags: c#, linq, join, castle-activerecord

**How can I execute a left join using LINQ and Castle Active Records?**

If tried the following:

```
from account in AccountRecord.Queryable
join s in SchoolRecord.Queryable on account equals s.Account into schools
where account.PaymentType == "S"
select new { Account = account, School = schools.ElementAt(0) };
```

but that threw me the following exception:

> Unable to cast object of type
>   'Remotion.Data.Linq.Clauses.GroupJoinClause'
>   to type
>   'Remotion.Data.Linq.Clauses.FromClauseBase'.

executing the following works (but its not what I want, because I need a left join):

```
from account in AccountRecord.Queryable
where account.PaymentType == "S"
from school in SchoolRecord.Queryable
where school.Account == account
select new { Account = account, School = school };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems this is not possible at the moment.

If I or someone else find(s) a working solution I will update this answer.

Answer (score -1):

Using the `DefaultIfEmpty()` may do it.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/d9a19de2-87c7-48ff-9c93-5fbcd0db3983/

Comment: This throws a `The method or operation is not implemented`-Exception at `NHibernate.Linq.Visitors.QueryModelVisitor.VisitGroupJoinClause(GroupJoinClause groupJoinClause, QueryModel queryModel, Int32 index)`...